# Jitter on iOS when scrolling past boundaries

Tags: ios, scrollview

I thought it was normal behaviour to be able to drag a UITableView (or other scrollable view) past its boundaries to a considerable extent.

I currently have a view where I can indeed do this, but while I'm dragging it down, the view will jump back step wise until it is in a normal position. This doesn't seem right. Is there any way to figure out why this is or how to tune this behaviour?

[image: The unwanted behavior]

Comment: This is very unclear wording and possibly broad too. Could you narrow it down with some code and maybe add gif of your described behavior for clarification?

Comment: I added a GIF. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Do you have a refreshControl (UIControl) there? It seems like that's what's causing it.

Comment: Please post some code...

Comment: @Michal Thanks! I had a refresh call in there that was called on didUpdateLocations and that is being called all the time, even if the location does not change (so also in Simulator). That fixed it and it makes the app feel much more solid.

Comment: If you add an answer, I'll mark that.

Comment: There, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a `refreshControl` active (`UIControl` object) in your scroll view. It usually behaves like this - pull, pause, go back.